# AnimationBuilder with FutureBuilder - How to execute animation after future returns and builds?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am making an api call to get some data and then I want to animate in (from the bottom) the widget that displays it.  The code for each piece works separately but I can't seem to figure out how to execute the animation after the FutureBuilder has returned from its builder function?  Where or how do I call `cardController.forward()`?

```
 Widget mapCard(Area area) {
return Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: AnimatedBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(_createHeroRoute(area));
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: cardMargin.value,
          width: 300,
          height: 150,
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'location',
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: 274,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Image.network(area.images[0].url,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 150,

                        //30, 42, 65
                        // 412A1E
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 42, 65),
                        ),
                        child:
                            Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.white))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    animation: cardController,

  ),
);
}
```

In the build stack:

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: fArea,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Area> snap) {
                    if (snap.hasData) {
                      return mapCard(snap.data);
                    } else {
                      return Text('here');
                    }
                  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can make `MapCard` a `StatefulWidget` and call `cardController.forward` in `initState`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cardController =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: -300.0).animate(cardController)
      ..addStatusListener((state) => print('$state'));
    cardController.forward();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class MapCard extends StatefulWidget {
  Area area;
  MapCard(Area data, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapCardState createState() => _MapCardState();
}

class _MapCardState extends State<MapCard> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController cardController;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cardController =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: -300.0).animate(cardController)
      ..addStatusListener((state) => print('$state'));
    cardController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    cardController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: cardController,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            //Navigator.of(context).push(_createHeroRoute(area));
          },
          child: Container(
            //margin: cardMargin.value,
            width: 300,
            height: 150,
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'location',
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      width: 274,
                      height: 150,
                      child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Container(
                          height: 150,

                          //30, 42, 65
                          // 412A1E
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 42, 65),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.white))),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, animation.value),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Area {
  String data;
  Area(this.data);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<Area> fArea;

  Future<Area> getArea() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    return Future.value(Area("data"));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fArea = getArea();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: fArea,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Area> snap) {
              switch (snap.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snap.hasData) {
                    return MapCard(snap.data);
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this only that the parent needs to control the animations so it complicates it because now need to use provider or some kind of state management to get child to animate.